# service.users().drafts().update to attach pdf

Tags: python, gmail-api

With this python function I'm trying to update a gmail draft attaching a pdf:

```
def create_draft_with_attachment(service, user_id, draft_id, attachment_path):
    draft = service.users().drafts().get(userId=user_id, id=draft_id, format='raw').execute()

    # Get the raw message from the draft
    updated_draft = service.users().drafts().update(userId=user_id, id=draft_id, body=message).execute()
    print(f'Draft updated with ID: {updated_draft["id"]}')
```

I am getting the following error:

`An error occurred: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/../drafts/r909917f03f925817019?alt=json&uploadType=resumable returned "Media type 'application/pdf' is not supported.". Details: "[{'message': "Media type 'application/pdf' is not supported. ", 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest'}]">`

I also tried to get the body of the email and using MIME module to make the attachments but then the content of the body structure was not preserved.

Comment: It seems the Python script you provided might be incomplete. To help you more effectively, could you please provide the missing parts to accurately reproduce your issue? This will allow the community members to offer you a more accurate solution.